# How to read each line into an integer array, from a file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

How do I read each line of a file opened in my C program to an integer array. 
I cannot use `fgets` and `sscanf` as the input is not known beforehand. The length of each row and the number of columns can vary.

Tried `fscanf`, `fgetc`, and others, but they seem to run into problems while detecting the newline. And I ended up reading the entire file together, instead of into different arrays.

e.g., the file contains:

```
1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3

2 3 4
```

This should be stored in `arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5} , arr2[] = {1,2,3} , arr3[] = {2,3,4}`

Comment: Is this a question about homework?

Comment: What was the code you tried with fscanf and fgetc?

Comment: Nope not homework :) Was messing about with Judy arrays and was trying something out.

Answer (score 2):

Feed characters into a per-line buffer. Upon end-of-line (i.e., when you hit a newline character `\n`), tokenize the buffer with [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) or similar. Read the tokens into a pre-allocated or resizable array or `struct` of your choice.